# django-admin --version not working

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.8

django-admin --version giving error that django command not found.

On attempting to reinstall, it shows that it is already installed.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a `--version`, there is [`version`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/django-admin/#determining-the-version) however....

> Run `django-admin version` to display the current Django version.

Comment: No,it is still not working and giving same error.Actually,problem is that django keyword is not getting identified.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to execute command then probably `django-admin` is not in your classpath.

try

```
which django-admin
```

to see where the file is. For me it is in `/home/athakur/.local/bin/django-admin`

If this is not working for you give full path. Eg.

```
python3 ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py version
```

If this works add `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py` to your classpath.